# Passing a Ruby variable in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, ruby

I have the following code in my HTML where I am trying to pass a Ruby variable to the JavaScript function. Can someone please help me with the syntax?

```
<% @level2.each_with_index do |row2, index2| %> 
................................................
................................................
<a href="javascript:validateUser_com("<%= #{index2} %>")" >Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using double quotes twice. For example, if `index2` is `1`, you end up with the following JavaScript:

```
<a href="javascript:validateUser_com("1")" >
```

Since you're using double quotes for the HTML attribute, you should escape the inner quotes or use single quotes. Furthermore, the Ruby expression is not a string, so there's no need for interpolation:

```
<a href="javascript:validateUser_com('<%= index2 %>')" >
```

Comment: The html page does not load....it shows some error in the syntax itself....multiple errors around the line....so definitely something wrong with the syntax.

Comment: Ah, not sure how I missed this, but what's inside the Ruby expression is not a string--so no need for `#{}`. I'll update the answer.